# KnockoutJS - split a string

Tags: knockout.js

Something that should be so simple, has been driving me nuts in Knockoutjs. Just to split an incoming string.

I have opts.value() from the calendar coming in and want to split it to remove the time, but it keeps returning "not a function". and doesn't like .split. Any ideas?

```
self.ShortDate = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.opts.value().split(" ",4);
    }, self);
```

Here is the string that is returned by opts.value "Wed Oct 14 2015 00:00:00 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Standard Time)"

Sorry for not including the VM, here is the relevant part from the https://github.com/MakerStudios/ko-calendar

```
self.opts = {
        value: ko.observable(),
        DateFromIn: ko.observable(),
        current: new Date(),
        deselectable: true,
        showCalendar: true,
        showToday: true,
        showTime: false,
        showNow: false,
        militaryTime: false,
        min: null,
        max: null,
        autoclose: false,
```

Comment: share up complete relevant part of vm . Try `self.opts().value.split(' ',4)` (i'm guessing - opts is observable inside to it you have plane js variable)

Comment: I have added more info Self.Opts.value it comes from here https://github.com/MakerStudios/ko-calendar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation of the ko-calendar](https://github.com/MakerStudios/ko-calendar#default-options) the `value` option is a `ko.observable([Date Object])` so it stores a `Date` object not a `string`.

So you need to convert it first to a string then you can do the split:

```
self.ShortDate = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.opts.value().toString().split(" ",4);
}, self);
```

However there are better options exist for formatting `Date` objects: [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)